# Error: Network Error with React Native, request .NET Core Web API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asp.net-core-webapi

(AXIOS GET)

I am requesting .NET Core Web API 2.1 with React Native, but the error I get on the console as follows:

*Note: Cors was granted permissions by .NET Core 2.1`.

Code:

```
return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:50000/api/values', {
  credentials: 'include'
})
.then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
)
.catch(
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Error:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:349)
    at D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (D:\Projeler\Mobile\ReactNative\primCepte\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297)
```

Comment: What's the Network tab indicate? (4xx, 5xx + Response)

Comment: Have you checked that it works by calling `http://127.0.0.1:50000/api/values` with Postman for example?

Comment: Yes, I checked and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.

Even though you don't get *CORS* error you might still be missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header which still *'erors'* your request.

You need to add CORS to your ASP.net core app.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
        builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }
    )
);
```

and then

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

before

```
app.UseMvc();
```

This is convenient and will allow **ANY** ajax request to your API, but its not ideal.

You can allow IP's and domains of your choosing. How to do that read more in [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)